# Remove value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am trying to figure out how if you are adding values to an array and then the same value comes up you have push it to the same array to not push it up and remove the duplicate of the value from the array.

This is my code below:

```
if (!_.includes(scope.index, val)) {
    scope.index.push(val);
} else {
    _.remove(scope.index, val);
   console.log(scope.index);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to avoid duplicates in an array? Simple JS would suffice for that. Just need to check the index of value in the array before pushing the same in it.

Comment: Ah its been a long day... Great idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `_.remove()` with a predicate function which checks if the current element equals to `val`:

```
_.remove(arr, x=> x === val)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as this in JS

```
if ( scope.index.indexOf( val ) != -1 )
{
  scope.index.push( val );
}
```

To remove the pushed value

```
var index = scope.index.indexOf( val );
scope.index.splice(index,1);
```

Comment: what about if the function gets clicked again and you need to remove the value that has already been pushed?

Comment: @MaxwellLynn Sorry for the delayed reply (weekend in India :)), please check the updated code.